# Why is it not possible to construct a `std::filesystem::path` from `std::filesystem::path` iterators?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

The following piece of code aims to strip the first part of a path in case it exists:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

std::filesystem::path strip_prefix(std::filesystem::path p)
{      
  if (auto it{p.begin()}; it != p.end())
  {
    ++it;
    return std::filesystem::path(it, p.end());
  }

  return p;
}
```

(See: https://godbolt.org/z/wkXhcw)

I was surprised to find out this does not work. The code does not compile since the path constructor only takes iterators that iterate over character sequences. I can see the use of that, but why limit construction to only those kind of iterators? In my opinion it is counter intuitive to not support constructing a path from its own iterators. As far as I know most other STL types do support this idiom.

What would be an efficient implementation to achieve the same goal, other than completely reconstructing a new path?

*Update*: in this context, I found the following discussion relevant/amusing: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-filesystem-path-frustration-td4641734.html. I agree with Dave here. I think seeing a path as a container of path elements is a very natural way to look at it (from a programmer's perspective).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution to the concatenating the segments to make a new `path` is just `std::accumulate()`.

For your particular use case, I'd do something like this:

```
std::filesystem::path strip_prefix(std::filesystem::path p)
{
    if(p.empty()) return p;
    return std::accumulate(std::next(p.begin()), p.end(), 
                           std::filesystem::path{}, std::divides{});
}
```

As for why there isn't a constructor (or maybe a free function) to do this? I don't know. This seems like a need that comes up a fair bit when working with paths, but the committee does tend to be reluctant to add convenience functions to standard classes if the same result can be achieved by a call to a standard algorithm.

Comment: I disagree that this type of range constructor would be classified as superfluous convenience function on the grounds that literally every other container (except `std::valarray` and `std::array`) has a range constructor.

Comment: @rubenvb Oh, _I'm_ not saying it would be superfluous. I'm just theorising that maybe the committee would.

Comment: The complicated thing with `path` is that it consumes character iterators, but yields segment iterators. I can't think of another `std` container with this behaviour.

Comment: I don't believe `path` is technically a container (and what you say might have a lot to do with it). Though it does already have character iterator range constructors, one could argue a segment iterator constructor wouldn't be so hard to add such that one can do `path p{other_path.begin(), other_path.end()-1};` or similar shenanigans.

Comment: @rubenvb, for the external API I think it would be more natural to see a path as a container of path segments. Relevant other discussion I just found: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-filesystem-path-frustration-td4641734.html

Comment: @T.C.Interesting. Which corner cases are those?

Comment: NTFS alternate data streams. If you have a filename that is `b:ads`, `/` will treat the `b:` part as a root-name and do bad things. Compare [LWG issue 3070](https://wg21.link/lwg3070).

Comment: +1 for `std::divides`.  Yep, that's intuitive! ;-)  (You don't have to explain it to me; I understand why that works.  I simply find it an amusing example of how well-meaning C++ library design inevitably lead to weird constructs.)

Comment: Not wrong, but I'm not convinced importing and using something called `divides` and `accumulate` is any better for the reader than a manual loop; short code isn't necessarily more readable. This really needs a proper constructor in the standard.